# Find object of given Type

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm in an odd situation. I have a horrendous number of classes that derive from each other and I store objects in various collections.

So for example:

```
Record <-- CostRecord <-- AccruedCostRecord
                      <-- PrepaidCostRecord
                      <-- StockRecord
```

The objects are stored in a List(Of Record) and I want to search a particular list for a record of a given type.

```
    Private Function findRecord(listToSearch As List(of Record), recordName As String, recordType As Type) As Record
        For i As Integer = 0 To listToSearch.Count - 1
            If listToSearch(i).name.equals(recordName)
                'If record is of type "recordType" then return it
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

Normally I would use the "TypeOf ... Is" operator as I am interested in the base class types too. So if I passed in "CostRecord" I would expect to retrieve a AccruedCostRecord, PrepaidCostRecord or StockRecord.

In this case I can't use TypeOf because it doesn't accept System.Type as an argument and I can't think of another way of telling it what I want.

I don't believe that "GetType" is going to help me here either because I'm interested in base classes.

Has anyone any ideas? Perhaps some kind of crazy Reflection magic?

Thanks

Comment: Use generics. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235246.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter How exactly would I go about using generics? The article you linked describes what to do if you're passing in a parameter of type T but in this case I'm not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method [`.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your type:

```
If recordType.IsAssignableFrom(listToSearch(i).GetType())
```

For example, if your list item is `AccruedCostRecord` and your `recordType` is `CostRecord`, this will return `True`.

Comment: This sounds useful.
What happens if my list item is `Cost` and my recordType is `CostRecord`?

Comment: That depends where `Cost` is in your type hierarchy - you've not mentioned that type before :-)

Comment: If your list item is `Record` and your `recordType` is `CostRecord` it'll return `False`.

Comment: Good, that's exactly what I'm after and it seems to be working! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite it with LINQ but as quick answer you may do this:

```
Private Function findRecord(listToSearch As List(of Record), recordName As String, recordType As Type) As Record
    For i As Integer = 0 To listToSearch.Count - 1
        If listToSearch(i).name.equals(recordName) And listToSearch(i).GetType() = recordType Then
            ' ...
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Key point is this comparison: `listToSearch(i).GetType() = recordType`, `GetType()` method (inherited from `Object`) will return object type as `Type` (then comparable with your parameter). With strict comparison it'll match only objects exactly of given type (then if you specify `PrepaidCostRecord` for `recordType` it'll match only that and if you specify `CostRecord` then it won't match anything).

To include derived classes (so you can specify, for example, `CostRecord` for your parameter `recordType` and it'll match all derived classes like `PrepaidCostRecord` but not ancestors like `Record`) you just have to change it to:

```
recordType.IsAssignableFrom(listToSearch(i).GetType())
```

Final code will then be:

```
Private Function findRecord(listToSearch As List(of Record), recordName As String, recordType As Type) As Record
    For i As Integer = 0 To listToSearch.Count - 1
        If listToSearch(i).name.equals(recordName) And recordType.IsAssignableFrom(listToSearch(i).GetType()) Then
            ' ...
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Now it's time to rewrite it with LINQ, for example:

```
Dim records = From record In listToSearch_
    Where record.name.equals(recordName) And recordType.IsAssignableFrom(record.GetType)
```

In your case you can rewrite it shorter as:

```
Private Function findRecord(listToSearch As List(of Record), recordName As String, recordType As Type) As Record
    findRecord = listToSearch.FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.name.equals(recordName) And recordType.IsAssignableFrom(r.GetType))
End Function
```

Comment: That won't meet the requirement of returning derived classes.

Comment: Thanks, this is quite comprehensive. I don't know anything about LINQ but suspect my manager will hate it - he prefers longer verbose code split up on many lines to improve readability!

Comment: @lilactiger89 you can split LINQ expression on many lines if he prefers that... :) Usually LINQ functions are very self descriptive, if you see "FirstOrDefault" you don't have to read 5 lines of code to understand what it does because it's clear at first sight.

Answer (score -1):

you can use GetType.BaseType to see if the base type is the class you are looking for. 
 If not you can go deeper in Gettype.Baseytpe.BaseType.

Comment: I thought of this but it seems to be a horrendously inefficient way of going about things!

Comment: I agree with you. The 'IsAssignableFrom' function seems to be the more elegant version.